# Updating the most recent document in mongoDB with all fields value same except for the timestamp field through Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with 100 documents out of which 4 documents have exactly same values for all the fields except for a different timestamp value. I want to change the most recent document among this 4 documents. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Query the collection on the fields they have the same values for, sort by timestamp and return the latest.

```
const myDoc = db.collection.findOne({ fieldA: 'valA', fieldB: 'valB', ... }).sort({ timestamp: -1 });
db.collection.update(myDoc, { fieldA: 'newValA', ... });
```

**Update: How to query your db in java**

```
// setup your db connection
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(...);
DB db = client.getDB("yourDbName");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collectionName");

// set up the query for the fields you want to use
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("fieldA", "valA");
query.put("fieldB", "valB");
// etc

// create the object for sorting by timestamp
BasicDBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("timestamp", -1);

// query the database
Document mostRecent = (Document)collection.find(query).sort(sort).first();
```

Comment: I wanted a java code for the same. Could you help me with that. I am new so facing difficulty in doing so.

Comment: The logic will be identical you only have to "translate" it to your java API. i) create the query object (`BasicDBObject query  = new BasicDBObject();`) and add the fields (`query.put("fieldA", "valA");`) then query your db with it.

Comment: in java the collection.update takes in (DBObject,DBObject) so it gives error when i pass the 1st argument as a Document